# tinymce icons in internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, icons, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE but the images for the icons don't show up in Internet Explorer. I've checked the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625019/how-do-i-get-the-icons-of-tinymce-to-show), but I'm already doing the necessary code right.

In firebug when I'm using firefox, I can check the CSS and I do see that the image (img/icons.gif) is loading, so it must be loading in IE as well, but the toolbar is still blank. If I roll over the toolbar, I get the right tooltips and can figure out which button it is, which means the buttons in the advacned are working. I think the problem is in CSS.

I'm using the latest jQuery version of TinyMCE, and running IE9. When I try it in compatibility view of IE9, it does show up the icons.

Is there any specific CSS that needs to be tweaked for IE9?

Comment: Which DOCTYPE does your IE show? Which rendering engine is used on page load, without switching the rendering mode manually?

Comment: <!-- DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" -->

I'm not too familiar with rendering engines, how can I check which engine is being used?

Comment: My< question was not, which DOCTYPE yuo had insertedm but which one does IE actually see. Open the IE developer tolls and lokk which engine it uses (IE7, IE8, IE9?).

Comment: Okay I've rechecked - no matter which "Browser Mode" I see the page, it's only when I'm using "Document Mode" IE7 that the images show up.

Comment: It is also an error if "Browser Mode" and "Document Mode" are different right after page load, without having switched to compatibility mode.

Comment: Can you share a link to the site with this problem?

Comment: Are you using a responsive layout? You might want to try this.
`.mceEditor img { max-width: none; }`

Comment: @aurevilly, that was it! thank you! I can see all toolbar buttons now! If you put that down as answer, I'll select it as the right answer.

Comment: Cool. I've put back my anwser up so you can accept :) Have a good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a responsive layout? If so, try this:

```
.mceEditor img {
 max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was the **blocking of download of fonts** in the **IE-Security-Settings**. (IE -> Internet Options -> tab 'security' ) Here the screenshot of the settings in a German IE:

[image: settings dialog in German IE 11]

If you cannot change the security settings, You can find a proposal [here in TinyMce UserGroup](http://archive.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=30966) to use a skin that does not use fonts.  You can download the skin 'lightgraynofonts' [here](http://archive.tinymce.com/download/plugins_view.php?id=34). Extract the zip-file into a directory **/tinymce/skins/lightgraynofonts** and initialize the tinymce editor like this:

```
                tinyMCE.init({
                            selector: ideditor,
                            theme: "modern",
                            skin: "lightgraynofonts",** ...
```