# TinyMCE 4 not showing toolbar icons in IE9 (any mode)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tinymce, tinymce-4

TinyMCE has this easy to use code, but I cannot see the toolbar icons in IE9 (the imgs don't load it seems).

```
<html>
      <head><!-- CDN hosted by Cachefly -->
         <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
         <script>        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>
      </head>
      <body>
            <textarea>Your content here.</textarea>
      </body>
</html>
```

I've seen this similar post ([tinymce icons in internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798667/tinymce-icons-in-internet-explorer)), but the advice made no difference for me.

I've tried putting the browser in different modes, nothing worked.  The only time I saw it work in IE was inside the EditPlus embedded browser, but I don't know exactly what that is.

Works nicely in Chrome.

EDIT- does work in IE when the file is loaded directly, eg. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tiny.html

Thanks.

Comment: "the imgs don't load it seems". Do you see messages about it in javascript console?

Comment: @GlenSwift no nothing in the console and I can't even find where the imgs should be specified in F12, just markup like this with no images specified in the style <div id="mce_4" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-last" role="button" tabIndex="-1" aria-labeledby="mce_4" aria-label="Italic"><button role="presentation" tabIndex="-1" type="button"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-italic"></i></button></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to check with IE is the font download security setting. If the setting is set to "Disable" then the web font icons will not display because the font cannot be downloaded. The setting can be found by clicking the Custom level... button on the Security tab of the Internet Options dialog which can be accessed under Tools > Internet options.

Comment: That was it - don't know what the default for IE11 is but that was the problem here.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE 4 uses a webfont containg all the icons. Make sure that they get loaded and that you allow cross-origin when loading the font with the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: Sounded promising, I added that header to my ASPX page's respibse (and verified it gets to the browser), but it made no difference and I found that the eot file is not requested at all.  Whereas when I loaded the page from the filesystem it did request the eot.  Maybe it's just a bug in tinymce.

Answer (score 0):

When I inspected the toolbar icons: I found that they are web fonts

```
<i class="mce-ico mce-i-bold"></i>
```

like this stands for bold. That means as rightly said TINYMCE are using web fonts for the toolbar, which are not showing up.

There are some questions which answers the same issue on IE 9 and previous versions of chrome. Here are the link

[Fontawesome Icons not working on IE9 and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685742/fontawesome-icons-not-working-on-ie9-and-chrome)

which says:

For the examples given below, assume that a document is located at http://example.com/page.html and all URL's link to valid font resources supported by the user agent. Fonts defined with the ‘src’ descriptor values below will be loaded:

```
/* same origin (i.e. domain, scheme, port match document) */
src: url(fonts/simple.woff);

/* data url's with no redirects are treated as same origin */
src: url("data:application/font-woff;base64,...");

/* cross origin, different domain */
/* Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header set to '*' */
src: url(http://another.example.com/fonts/simple.woff);
```

Fonts defined with the ‘src’ descriptor values below will fail to load:

```
 /* cross origin, different scheme */
 /* no Access-Control-xxx headers in response */
 src: url(https://example.com/fonts/simple.woff);

/* cross origin, different domain */
/* no Access-Control-xxx headers in response */
src: url(http://another.example.com/fonts/simple.woff);
```

**As seen on github https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/tree/master/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/fonts they are using icomoon fonts. So, download those and use on your own server. Hope it solves the purpose.**